# How does Rails type cast the result of array_agg() function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to apply this in-line view trick https://gist.github.com/jturkel/7917985#file-inline_view_model-rb in Rails 4. but there is one column in my view will returns an array generated from postgresql's build function `array_agg()`.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  defult_scope { set_from_clause }

  def self.set_from_clause
    query = Product.joins(:tags)
              .group("products.id")
              .select("products.id", "Array_agg('tags.id') AS tag_ids")

    from(query, table_name)
  end

  def self.columns
   [
      ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new('product_id', nil, ActiveRecord::Type::String.new),
      ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new('tag_ids', nil, ActiveRecord::Type::Integer.new),
    ]
  end
end
```

This example code doesn't work, because the value returned by `Array_agg` cannot be typcasted properly.
I wonder is there is a way to make this trick works with the `tag_ids` in the example.

Comment: It seems to work as is with Rails 5.2 | For others getting there because of the title, I suggest using json_agg and JSON.parse

Comment: I've used `json_agg` instead of `array_agg` in combination with JSON.parse and successfully parse postgess array

Answer (score 1):

use `json_agg` instead of `array_agg` and then parse it using `JSON.parse` method.
This work for me.